# How to Handle Error in S3 browser upload via POST

Tags: post, browser, error-handling, upload, amazon-s3

I am newbie to S3. Trying to catch errors in S3 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/ErrorResponses.html

My code  sample:

```
{"expiration": "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "johnsmith"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
    {"acl": "private"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["eq", "$Content-Type", "application/msword,application/pdf"],
    ["content-length-range", 2048, 20971520 ]
  ]
}'; 



<form action="http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" >
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId " value="15B4D3461F177624206A" />
<input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="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" />
<input type="hidden" name="Signature" value="2qCp0odXe7A9IYyUVqn0w2adtCA=" />
File: <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
</form>
```

Want to catch error if file is failed to upload or expired. To check content type, content length range.

Getting proper success callback variable like bucket, key, etag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: My original answer used iframes but I finally got the XMLHttpRequest to work which I think it is a cleaner approach.

I've had the same problem. My requirements were:

- I didn't want to use flash
- I didn't want the user to see the AWS error XML

There are plenty of solutions scattered all over the internet. I got it to work in two versions:

1. Using an iFrame to render the POST result and by trying to access the uploaded file (in my case, an image) to check if the upload worked or not: https://gist.github.com/joaoffcosta/5728483
2. Using XMLHttpRequest to make the request and handle progress, completion and premature failure: https://gist.github.com/joaoffcosta/5729398 (*Best solution IMO*)

In both solutions, your S3 Bucket should allow 'Everyone' to 'Upload/Delete'.
Additionally, the XMLHttpRequest solution requires you to configure CORS on your bucket. To do it you should go to your bucket 'Permissions', press 'Add CORS Configuration' and add something like this:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://your_website_or_localhost_server/</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1):

using simple ajax form post...

```
<script>
  function uploadFile() {
    var file_name = $('#form1 :input[name="file"]').val().split('\\').pop();
    if(!file_name || file_name.length === 0) {
      alert('please choose file')
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "/getS3FormData.php",
      cache: false,
      type: 'GET',
      data: {file_name : file_name} ,
      async: false,
      success: function (response) {
        var s3 = JSON.parse(response);
        handleFileUpload(s3);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        alert("Upload FAILED  :-( Retry.");
      }
    });
  }


function handleFileUpload(s3) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('key', s3.key);
  fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', s3.AWSAccessKeyId);
  fd.append('acl', s3.acl);
  fd.append('policy', s3.policy);
  fd.append('signature', s3.signature);
  fd.append('Content-Type', s3.content_type);

  var file = $('#form1').find('input[name=file]')[0].files[0];      
  fd.append("file", file);

  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Upload in progress";
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: s3.url,
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      window.onbeforeunload = null;
      window.location.href = s3.success_action_redirect;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      window.onbeforeunload = null;
      alert('Upload Failed, Please try again');
    }
  });
}
```

html form

```
  <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input type="file" name="file"></input>
    <input type="submit" onclick="uploadFile(); return false;" value="Upload">
  </form>
```